# VPN on Chrome OS through Android app stopped working

Tags: vpn, android, google-chrome-os

I have been using a VPN on Chrome OS using the Android app `OpenVPN client free` for 30 days with no issue.

Today, probably after an update of the app, the VPN only works for other Android applications and not for the full Chrome OS.

Is there a fix for this?

EDIT:

The situation seems to be very unstable. It was working again this morning and after 3-4 hours of work connected at the vpn it suddenly stopped working again

EDIT 2:
I have noticed that now I see the two different behaviors according if I am using the house wifi or a 4g mobile wifi .   I can't really explain this.

Comment: suddenly now the vpn connection seems to work also on the main chrome os  (as previously)

Answer (score 0):

I search the following two articles, they explain the same problem as you, and there is a way we can try.

[image]

The way is mentioned in it:
[Dealing with VPNs on a Chromebook running Android apps](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3123798/chromebooks/dealing-with-vpns-on-a-chromebook-running-android-apps.html)

[Android/Chrome OS VPN Integration](https://www.finjanmobile.com/android-chrome-os-vpn-integration/)

Comment: Could it be related to the date on the client/server, which sometime later was corrected via ntp?

Comment: What I am experiencing is different from what the article says. As I was able to use vpn from android APP with the chrome OS itself